# How to get the all songs without selection

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i get the all selected songs from the picker using MPMediaPickerController.But i need to get all the songs information with out selection.That means without showing the picker i need to get the all songs information.So please anyone tell me how to get that information.